# Do Until Loop Condition Met - but Loop continues - Powershell

Tags: powershell, do-loops

Hi I have an issue in powershell where the Do Until Condition is true, but the loop doesn't stop. If I change the -eq to 0. It will stop... Basically what this should do is get the number of computers in the text file. Store that number in $count. Then restart the service for each computer in the list until it reaches the last one.

```
$computers = gc C:\temp\computers.txt
$count = $computers.count
Do {
   foreach($computer in $computers){
        $readCount = $computer.ReadCount
        gwmi win32_service -ComputerName $computer | where {$_.name -like "*was*"} | Restart-Service
   } 
}
Until (($count - $readCount) -eq 1)
```

Comment: You iterate over all computers inside `foreach` loop and `Until` condition checked only once iteration done. Since `ReadCount` property one-based, `$readCount` will be equals to `$count`, so your `Until` condition is never met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `Do-Until` loop here since you can just iterate over the computers. To skip the last computer, use the [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) cmdlet with the `-SkipLast 1` parameter:

```
Get-Content 'C:\temp\computers.txt' | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | Forach-Object {
    gwmi win32_service -ComputerName $computer | 
        where {$_.name -like "*was*"} | 
        Restart-Service
}
```

Comment: Well I don't want it to iterate through the entire list, I just want all computers but the last remaining one. Basically I want to leave the service running on one computer.

Comment: Oh nice I didn't realize there is a -skiplast .... Ok that works. But Can you explain why my condition in the Do Until is true but the loop continues on. On a side note, I moved the $readcount outside of the foreach loop and it at least allows the loop to stop... However even when the -eq 1, it still hits the foreach and restarts the service on the last computer.

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer again and added an explanation.

Comment: Either way I accept your answer, as it at least does the job. I'm just frustrated that Do Until isn't working as I expected.

Comment: Hmm.. Well I set StrictMode but it doesn't bubble up an error about no readcount. If I do a $computer.readcount it definitely spits out a number to me.

Comment: Hm, I get an error when I use Strict Mode. Maybe different PowerShell version? However, your Do-Until loop is wrong there since you iterating over *EACH* computer in it.

Comment: Yea I'm using Powershell v5. I follow what your saying though. I like the skiplast approach anyway.

Comment: @jisaak `Get-Content` adds `ReadCount` property to returned objects.

Comment: @PetSerAl Oh, I used an array and added a few strings in there to test the script. I didn't knew that, thanks!